# Using Stun's server reflexive transport

Tags: udp, webrtc, udpclient, stun

I am trying to develop my own Lite-ICE client. I am able to get the STUN response which gives me my server reflexive addresses. The question that I have concerns steps after that.

So, I have received IP1 and Port1 as my server reflexive addresses from the STUN server assigned to my STUN client with local address L-IP1 and L-Port1.

I understand how it works if L-IP1 amd L-Port1 are multiplexed to send/receive non-STUN messages to/from remote server.

What if I want another application, a completely separate process to use the same bindings? So, can I start another application to bound the UDP port to L-Port1 too? If so, will both the applications (STUN) and this other application receive message from the remote servers with destination set to IP1 and Port1 (from the remote server's perspective)? And the one that does not understand the message type or method, simply ignores it? Is that how it normally work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What if I want another application, a completely separate process to use the same bindings?

You typically have each application get obtain its own bindings with a different local port.

> So, can I start another application to bound the UDP port to L-Port1 too?

You'll get a socket bind error if another process has a socket bound to the same local port.  There are ways around this, but read on, this isn't what you likely want.

> If so, will both the applications (STUN) and this other application receive message from the remote servers with destination set to IP1 and Port1 (from the remote server's perspective)?

You can use the SO_REUSEADDR option.  However, if you have two processes with sockets to the same local UDP port, incoming packets for that port will be routed to either socket. (First one to call recvfrom gets the packet - otherwise, it's non-deterministic).

> And the one that does not understand the message type or method, simply ignores it? Is that how it normally work?

No.

I think what you are saying is that you are doing STUN in one process, but want the actual application that uses those bindings to run in another process.  Just have your application do the STUN bindings itself and simply re-use the socket for data.  If you attempt to multiplex STUN and application data over the same socket, you'll need to have (your own) code to distinguish between each.